# Current amplification by 25 times

Tags: power, current

I use a dc generator of the rating 36v and 1.5 amps, I need to amplify the current to 50 amps and voltage to 12v. What should I use to get this amplification.

Comment: You will need an additional source of power.

Comment: I would guess that you don't even really want to do that. XY-problem, that is.

Comment: Describe what the thing you need to *achieve* is, what you want to build over all. As you ask this right now, everyone wonders what you're doing and why, and all answers will be incomplete. **edit** your question to include all backgroud of what you're doing! That's more work, but it allows proper answers, and I can retract my "close because it's too unclear what you want" vote.

Comment: An ordinary automobile alternator ought to be able to manage 600W output, but you'll need to turn it with sufficient power as they're quite inefficient, but often free. Find a BLDC motor of >600W rating, they're far more efficient and smaller, but pricey.

Answer (score 5):

Generator rated 54 watts, power requirement 600 watts. You're [gonna need a bigger generator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2I91DJZKRxs), if you want power continuously.

If you're happy to have an occasional pulse of power, then you can charge some batteries or capacitors, and discharge them for a fraction of the time that they charge for, maybe 5% of the charge time. This gives you the same average power over a long period, but could give the 600 watts peak pulse power that you want. The length of the pulse would decide whether capacitors are batteries are required.

Answer (score 3):

This is physically impossible with your current setup.

You have 36*1.5 = 54 watt in.

You want 12*50 = 600 watt out.

You need another generator.

Comment: can you please suggest a generator with very low weight that could deliver 50A, it’ll be driven by an engine.

Comment: @abhijithjagadeesh you will need an engine that can produce much more mechanical power than your current engine does. So, this puts this even further down into the "you don't have much idea of what you're doing, but you're also not asking a question with sufficient background".

Comment: How is this even related to the engine I use? I thought it depends on the generator.  And what kind of background information do you need ? The engine delivers 1.5hp at 9500 rpm.

Comment: @abhijithjagadeesh, where do you think the generator gets its power? If the motor can't produce 600 W, it can't drive a generator to produce 600 W. (1.5 HP > 600 W so you may be okay, but is the generator running at 9500 rpm?)